# This code should show error as there is extra tag than dtd. But it's not showing any error. What's the fault?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dtd

This code should show error as there is extra tag than dtd. But it's not showing any error. What's the fault?

```
<!DOCTYPE emaildetails [
    <!ELEMENT email ( to, from, subject, body )>
    <!ELEMENT to ( #PCDATA )>
    <!ELEMENT from ( #PCDATA )>
    <!ELEMENT subject ( #PCDATA )>
    <!ELEMENT body ( #PCDATA )>
    ]>


<emaildetails>
<email>
    <to>abc@gmail.com</to>
    <from>xyz@gmail.com</from>
    <subject>Hello</subject>
    <help>me</help>
    <body>How are you?</body>
</email>
<email>
    <to>mno@gmail.com</to>
    <from>xyz@gmail.com</from>
    <subject>Good</subject>
    <body>I am fine</body>
    <help>Me</help>
</email>
</emaildetails>
```

Comment: First of all, `emaildetails` is not declared. Then `email` is designed to contain `to`, `from`, `subject`, `body` (2nd line of your file). But in the XML, there are some extra `<help>`tags, yielding to your error.

Comment: Yeah that's right but this code isn't showing error instead it run smoothly.

Comment: OK so how are you parsing it? XML won't parse by itself.